# elasticsearch.yml remains empty after running Elastic Search on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, yaml, kibana

I am using Elastic Search 8.12. It contains `elasticsearch.yml` file which is all commented. I ran it for the first time and expected that it will write something in this file as I have seen with other examples but even after running Elastic Search, this `elasticsearch.yml` file remains commented.

I am able to open `http://localhost:9200` in browser and it works but I am unable to integrate Elastic Search with kibana because no token or other things are generated.

Is there a default uncommented `elasticsearch.yml` file which I can use or some way to make Elastic Search write something in it?

Comment: Integrate ES with Kibana and `elasticsearch.yml` file are two different things. There is a script to generate the token for integration: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/create-enrollment-token.html

Comment: If you pass the `--verbose` flag to Elasticsearch when you start it, it should tell you why it is skipping auto-configuration.